# Multilevel menu with nested ul tags

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out how to make the following menu working properly. When you hover on nested elements of first ul, it brings to first nested item of next ul, and the same happens when you try to hover on second nested element. What do I need to add into CSS to separate this elements from each other?

```
    <style>
        #blok li{
            padding-bottom: 1px;
            position: relative;
            list-style: none;
        }
        #blok ul{
            width: 140px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 160px;
            padding-left: 1px;
            visibility: hidden;
        }
        #blok li:hover ul{
            visibility: visible;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
        }
        #blok a, #blok li:hover li a{
            display: block;
            font: 14px/30px calibri;
            font-weight: bolder;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 0 10px;
            width: 140px;
            color: black;
            background-color: hsl(120, 75%, 50%);
        }
        #blok li:hover a, #blok li:hover li:hover a{
            background-color: hsl(120, 80%, 15%);
            color: white;
            text-decoration: underline overline;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="blok">
        <li><a href="start.html">Start</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="forum.html">Forum</a></li>
                <li><a href="aboutus.html">O nas</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="nowe.html">Aktualności</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="newsy.html">Newsy</a></li>
                <li><a href="wydarzenia.html">Wydarzenia</a></li>
                <li><a href="technologia.html">Technologia</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="szkolenia.html">Szkolenia</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="kurs1.html">HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="kurs2.html">CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="kurs3.html">Javascript</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="uslugi.html">Usługi</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="online.html">Kursy online</a></li>
                <li><a href="skladanie.html">Zestawy komputerowe</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Comment: Please explain the problem. It is not understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem 1. Switching list when hovering the second element of a nested list**

Your nested lists are on the same level as your main list, your need to put your nested lists on top of the main list to solve that.

Add this rule and it should work:

`#blok ul {
   z-index: 2; /* Or anything greater than 1 */
 }`

**Problem 2. Nested lists appearing when hovering next to the main list and not only on it**

Put your background-colors in comment then use a background-color on `#blok li` to see the boundaries of this element and you'll understand why this happens.

You need your `#blok li` elements to be shorter, for now they're take the whole width of the container.

Two way to solve that.

1.

```
#blok {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

#blok li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

or

2.

```
#blok li {
  width: 160px;
}

#blok a,
#blok li:hover li a {
  width: calc(100% - 2 * 10px);
}
```

I'm using your markup here, but it would be better to separate `#blok` a and `#blok li:hover li a`